# Firestore where 'IN' query on google-cloud firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

(Using typescript for better readability. Vanilla js is always welcome)

Nodejs App, using these imports:

`import { FieldPath, DocumentReference } from '@google-cloud/firestore';`

and this function

```js
async getByIds(ids: DocumentReference[]) {
    const collection = this.db.client.collection('authors');
    const query = await collection.where(FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ids).get();

    return query.docs.map(d => ({ id: d.id, ...d.data() }));
}
```

returns this very specific error:

`The corresponding value for FieldPath.documentId() must be a string or a DocumentReference.`

The debugger confirms  that ids is in fact a DocumentReference array.

Maybe the `@google-cloud/firestore` package isn't aligned to the firebase one?

**EDIT:**
as noted by Doug in it's comment, I forgot to put the code for `this.db.client`. Here you are:

```js
export class DatabaseProvider {
    private _db: Firestore;
    get client(): Firestore {
        return this._db;
    }

    constructor() {
        this._db = new Firestore({
            projectId: ...,
            keyFilename: ...
        });
    }
}
```

And used as

```js
const db = new DatabaseProvider();
```

Comment: "*Maybe the @google-cloud/firestore package isn't aligned to the firebase one?*" - are you saying that you're also using firebase-admin?  If so, could you edit the question show the **entire, minimal** code that exhibits this issue?  As show right now, we don't know what `this.db` or `this.db.client` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you're trying to do is a batch get, which is available via a different method: [`getAll()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#getAll). I think you want this:

```
async getByIds(ids: DocumentReference[]) {
  return this.db.client.getAll(...ids);
}
```

Comment: We got our champ here: getAll did the trick. Just edit your answer for future readers and use the spread operator `getAll(...ids)`. It's useful to add the [link](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/global.html#ReadOptions)`fieldMask` parameter to `getAll()` to narrow the search to the selected collections.